# Wurfl license in a commercial product

Tags: licensing, wurfl

I noticed that WURFL changed his license model on 30 august 2010. Can please anyone explain me, can I use it with new license in commercial product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Yeah, i know. now it's offtopic, but that time it wasn't too much offtopic, and question is almost 4 years old. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See licensing info for commercial use at [ScientaMobile](http://www.scientiamobile.com/products)

Comment: Based on it, I can use wurlf free of charge only for open source project under AGPL license? And if I want to use it in my commercial project - I should pay for it?

Comment: @PhoeniXX: I have no idea, but I believe the ScientaMobile webpage has the information you want if you read it carefully. (edit) In the matrix it is stated that license for commercial use starts at 1500$.

Answer (score 0):

A cloud offering should be making it's debut in roughly a month, and may save you some $ depending on your usage.  A free version with limited capabilities will likely be included as well.